# What happens when I ally with a faction?

Tags: battletech, battletech-flashpoint

In the Battletech expansion Flashpoint it's possible to ally with a faction if your reputation with them is high enough.

What are the advantages and drawbacks of allying yourself with a faction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By entering into an Alliance, you mark yourself an ally of that faction - and an enemy of that faction's enemies.

Faction stores - In addition to making higher difficulty contracts and salvage available, Alliances also allow you to access faction-specific stores containing items you might not find anywhere else.

https://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/index.php?threads/live-battletech-update-1-3-flashpoint-expansion-and-localization-beta-release-notes.1131637/

Comment: Additionally, each faction has a Flashpoint which unlocks when you ally with them.

Comment: You will also have your reputation with enemies of the faction reduced to zero and you can not raise the reputation for the faction above zero.  It also says somewhere that you can not take missions against the interests of your ally.